# C# Specify that a derived field is derived from its original class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say I have a the classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` with `B:A` and `D:C`.

`A` has a field with a `C` object that gets inherited to `B` and is used in different methods in `A`. I know want to specify that in `B`, it is not only a `C` object, but a `D` object, but still utilize the methods in `A` that operate on the `C` object.

```
public class A 
{
    public C Obj { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff with Obj (C)
    }
}


public class B : A 
{
    public D Obj { get; set; } // This should also be the C Obj in A

    public void DoMoreStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff with Obj (D)
    }
}

public class C 
{
    // ...
}

public class D : C
{
    // ...
}
```

Specifically I need this to implement Binary Trees. A Binary-Search-Tree (BST) has a root that is a BST-Node and provides different methods that utilize it. A Red-Black-Tree is also a BST but the root is a RBT-Node, that is also a BST-Node, but additionally has a color attribute.

Comment: These kinds of questions are **way** easier to grok if you use different, more meaningful, names. e.g. rather than `A` use `Animal`.

Comment: Interfaces. You want them.

Comment: or keyword `new`. You want it too. (like: `public new D Obj { get; set; }`)

Comment: @vasily.sib - Oh, no, not `new`. That's very very rarely ever a good idea.

Comment: @Enigmativity, totaly agreed: it is a realy bad idea for real life application. But, for example applications, like this, it looks suitable:\ I mean - it is interesting and fun for education and exploring, meanwhile it is "DO-NOT" for production.

Answer (score 4):

You can do what you want with a generic base class. Try starting with this:

```
public abstract class A<T> where T : C
{
    public T Obj { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(this.Obj.GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

Now you can define `A` and `B` easily:

```
public class A : A<C>
{
}

public class B : A<D>
{
    public void DoMoreStuff()
    {
        this.DoStuff();
        Console.WriteLine(this.Obj.GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

If I run this code:

```
var a = new A() { Obj = new C() };
var b = new B() { Obj = new D() };

a.DoStuff();

Console.WriteLine("...");

b.DoMoreStuff();
```

I get:

```
C
C
...
D
D
D
```

Comment: Actually, that's a better answer than mine. +1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Thanks. You do some good answers so that's high praise. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy using generics:

```
public class A<T> where T : C 
{
    public T Obj { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff with Obj (C)
    }
}


public class B<T> : A<T> where T : D // this condition is valid since D inherits C
{
    public T Obj { get; set; } 

    public void DoMoreStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff with Obj (D)
    }
}

public class C 
{
    // ...
}

public class D : C
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in some generics to gain access to the properties you want. I feel like this is a homework exercise, so I'll just give you the basics. See comments in the code for more details

```
public abstract class BaseTree<TNode>
    where TNode : BaseNode // TNode must be at least (base class) a BaseNode
{
    // Can be a collection as well, depending on your needs
    public TNode Node { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // Node is a BaseNode
    }
}

// Any node in this tree is a RedBlackNode
public class RedBlackTree : BaseTree<RedBlackNode>
{
    public void DoMoreStuff()
    {
        // Node is a RedBlackNode
    }
}

public abstract class BaseNode
{
}

public class RedBlackNode : BaseNode
{
}
```